# Argument of Different Data-Types

Tags: javascript, types, boolean, type-conversion, default-parameters

Is it a good idea / practice to do the following:

```
export const checkAndUpdateCredit = ( total, addback = false ) => {
 // here, addback can be an obj or boolean
 let value = total - addback.value
};
```

As per the comment, if the argument of `addback` isn't passed, it defaults to `false`, else an object is required to be passed. Here a single parameter can be either an `object` or a `boolean`. Is this a good practice / acceptable?

Comment: And what's the point of subtracting a number and a boolean?

Comment: what about `addback.value` ? if `addback` is `false`? you didn't handle this

Comment: thats the point, number - boolean  = number.

Comment: @Kayote number - (-1) for example? O_o

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer `const a=false; a==0` outputs true... `a===0` outputs false... `a==-1` outputs false... clearly I shouldn't be doing what I was doing above, however, it does work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a default value inside of addback

```
export const checkAndUpdateCredit = (total, addback = { value: 0 }) => {
//                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: absolutely and I think this is more sensible & less confusing than mine.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check for second `argument` existence.

**Note:** Second argument must be object with key `value`

```js
const checkAndUpdateCredit = ( total, addback ) => {
 // here, addback can be an obj or boolean
 let value = addback? total - addback.value : total;
  console.log(value);
};

checkAndUpdateCredit(10);

checkAndUpdateCredit(10, {value: 2});
```